# Is it possible to take the Limit of a Matrix?

Tags: probability, limits, markov-chains

Here is my understanding of (Discrete) Markov Chains:

Suppose there is a Discrete Markov Chain with 3 States $A$,$B$,$C$ and there are $N$ people

**1) Stationary Distribution:**

- Suppose at time=$n$, there are $\frac{n_i}{n_i+n_j+n_k}$ people in $A$, $\frac{n_j}{n_i+n_j+n_k}$ people in $B$ and $\frac{n_k}{n_i+n_j+n_k}$ people in C.
- $n_i$ + $n_j$ + $n_k$ = $N$
- If at time=$n+1$, there are still $\frac{n_i}{n_i+n_j+n_k}$ people in $A$, $\frac{n_j}{n_i+n_j+n_k}$ people in $B$ and $\frac{n_k}{n_i+n_j+n_k}$ people in C - then $n_1, n_2, n_3$ is considered as the Stationary Distribution

Mathematically, we can say -  for a transition matrix $P$ : $\pi$ is a Stationary Distribution if $\pi$ satisfies the following :

$$\pi = \pi P$$

Solving for $\pi$ is like solving a system of linear equatiosn.

**2) Limiting Distribution:**

- Suppose at time=$0$, there are $\frac{n_i}{n_i+n_j+n_k}$ people in $A$, $\frac{n_j}{n_i+n_j+n_k}$ people in $B$ and $\frac{n_k}{n_i+n_j+n_k}$ people in C.
- $n_i$ + $n_j$ + $n_k$ = $N$
- After infinite time steps, there are now $m_1$ people in $A$, $m_2$ people in $B$ and $m_3$ people in C.
- $m_1$ + $m_2$ + $m_3$ =  $N$
- If after infinite time steps, for all possible sets of ($n_i,n_j,n_k$)  ... there are still $m_1$ people in $A$, $m_2$ people in $B$ and $m_3$ people in C : $(m_1, m_2, m_3)$ is considered as the Limiting Distribution

Mathematically, we can say - for a transition matrix $P$, any initial distribution $\pi_0$ : $\pi$ is a Limiting Distribution if the following limit exists :

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \pi = \pi_0 P^n$$

**My Question:** Given a Markov Chain, it seems straightforward to obtain the Stationary Distribution ... but I am not sure how we would try and obtain the Limiting Distribution. I understanding that if you can show that a Markov Chain is Ergodic (i.e. both irreducible and aperiodic), then the Limiting Distribution is equivalent to the Stationary Distribution.

But from a general perspective, without relying on this Ergodic fact, it seems like you would need to prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \pi_0 P^n$ is the same for all $\pi_0$.

As such, I am not sure how this can be proven as it would require taking the limit of a matrix.

For a specific Markov Chain, I could take different values of $\pi_0$, and manually exponentiate $P$ to some large $n$ (e.g. $n$ = 100) and check if $\pi$ remains the same. But of course this is not a mathematical proof.

Thus, for a given matrix $P$, is it possible to prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \pi_0 P^n$ is the same for all $\pi_0$?

Thanks!

- The only understandable reference I found on this:https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter11/11_2_6_stationary_and_limiting_distributions.php

Comment: Limit of a matrix, no. Limit of a *sequence of matrices*, sure. Defined much as for limit of a sequence of numbers. You just need a concept of the distance between two matrices, and there are many reasonable options. I bet you can think of some.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: thank you so much for your reply! I am not quite sure I fully understand. If you have time, can you please elaborate and show me how I directly evaluate the limiting distribution of a Markov Chain? Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob Your question goes way beyond what Gerry said. Gerry explained what limits of a sequence of matrices should mean, but you're asking for a more technical computation; it's not really an elaboration, it's something different. The question in your title doesn't match what you actually want to know, which is a problem

Comment: Speaking about matrices in general, if ${\bf R}^m$ has a basis $\{v_1,v_2,\dotsc,v_m\}$ consisting of eigenvectors of an $m\times m$ matrix $P$, then for any vector $v$, $$P^nv=c_1\lambda_1^nv_1+c_2\lambda_2^nv_2+\dotsb+c_m\lambda_m^nv_m$$ where $\lambda_j$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector $v_j$, and the $c_j$ are given by $v=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\dotsb+c_mv_m$. If (as may be the case for Markov stuff) $\lambda_1=1$ and $|\lambda_j|<1$ for $2\le j\le m$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}P^nv$ exists and equals $c_1v_1$.

Comment: I think I was able to solve my problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4851874/proving-the-limit-of-a-matrix