# Proving the Limit of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the following matrix: \begin{equation}
P = \begin{bmatrix}
1-a & a \\[5pt]
b & 1-b
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}

I am trying to prove the following statement:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P^n=\frac{1}{a+b} \begin{bmatrix}
b & a \\[5pt]
b & a
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Here is what I tried so far:

- For $n=2$: $P^2 = P \cdot P$

$$ P^2 =  \begin{bmatrix} 1-a & a \\ b & 1-b \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1-a & a \\ b & 1-b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} (1-a)^2 + ab & a(1-a) + a(1-b) \\ b(1-a) + b(1-b) & ab + (1-b)^2 \end{bmatrix}.$$

$$P^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 - 2a + a^2 + ab & a - a^2 + a - ab \\ b - ab + b - b^2 & ab + 1 - 2b + b^2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 - a + ab & a \\ b & 1 - b + ab \end{bmatrix}.$$

- For $n$ = 3: $P^3 = P^2 \cdot P$

$$P^3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 - a + ab & a \\ b & 1 - b + ab \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1-a & a \\ b & 1-b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} (1 - a + ab)(1 - a) + ab & (1 - a + ab)a + a(1 - b) \\ b(1 - a) + b(1 - b + ab) & ba + (1 - b + ab)(1 - b) \end{bmatrix}.$$

$$P^3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 - a + a^2 - a^2b + ab & a - a^2 + a - ab \\ b - ab + b - b^2 + ab & ab + 1 - 2b + b^2 - ab \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 - a + a^2b & a \\ b & 1 - b + a^2b \end{bmatrix}.$$

- For $n=4$: $P^4$ =  $P^3 \cdot P$

$$P^4 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 - a + a^2b & a \\ b & 1 - b + a^2b \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1-a & a \\ b & 1-b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} (1 - a + a^2b)(1 - a) + ab & (1 - a + a^2b)a + a(1 - b) \\ b(1 - a) + b(1 - b + a^2b) & ba + (1 - b + a^2b)(1 - b) \end{bmatrix}.$$

$$P^4 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 - a + a^2 - a^3 + a^3b + ab & a - a^2 + a^2b \\ b - ab + a^2b & 1 - b + a^2 - a^3b + a^3b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 - a + a^3b & a + a^2b \\ b + a^2b & 1 - b + a^3b \end{bmatrix}.$$

- For $n=5$: $P^5 = P^4 \cdot P$

$$P^5 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 - a + a^3b & a + a^2b \\ b + a^2b & 1 - b + a^3b \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1-a & a \\ b & 1-b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} (1 - a + a^3b)(1 - a) + ab & (1 - a + a^3b)a + a(1 - b) \\ b(1 - a) + b(1 - b + a^3b) & ba + (1 - b + a^3b)(1 - b) \end{bmatrix}.$$

$$P^5 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 - a + a^2 - a^3 + a^4b + ab & a - a^2 + a^3b + a^2b \\ b - ab + a^3b + a^2b & 1 - b + a^2 - a^3b + a^4b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 - a + a^4b & a + a^3b \\ b + a^3b & 1 - b + a^4b \end{bmatrix}.$$

**My Question:** As $n$ increases, I can recognize the patterns in the diagonals of this matrix and the off-diagonals, but I am not sure what I can do to prove the original statement. I had originally thought of dividing the final product by $\frac{1}{a+b}$, but I don't think this will be of too much help.

Can someone please show me what to do from here?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think it converges? By the way, you can check that a necessary condition for the convergence of $P^n$ is that $-1<1-a-b\le1$, using the determinant.

Comment: @ Joshua: Thank you for your reply! I am trying to work through problems on this website: https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter11/11_2_6_stationary_and_limiting_distributions.php

Comment: You should try finding the eigenvalues. Hint: the rows add to 1.

Comment: Do you know how to *diagonalize* a matrix, stats? Given $P$, if you find invertible $Q$ and diagonal $D$ such that $P=Q^{-1}DQ$, then $P^n=Q^{-1}D^nQ$, and $D^n$ is easy, making $P^n$ easy.

Comment: @Joshua Tilley: thank you so much for your reply! I thought of taking the Eigenvalues, but I was not sure how exactly they would help me in proving this?

Comment: Use Gerry Myerson's tip - the diagonal matrix has the eigenvalues as its entries.

Comment: OK - I think I understand now... I will write my solution

Comment: thank you everyone! I think I was able to solve this!

Answer (score 2):

OP here - based on the advice provided by @Joshua Tilley and @Gerry Myerson, here is my attempt to answer my own question.

Starting with

\begin{equation}
P = \begin{bmatrix}
1-a & a \\[5pt]
b & 1-b
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
Here are the steps we would need.

**Step 1: Determine Eigenvalues**

$$P - λI = \begin{bmatrix}
 1-a-\lambda & a \\[5pt]
  b & 1-b-\lambda
  \end{bmatrix}.$$

For a general 2 x 2 matrix, the determinant is given by:
$$det(P - λI)  = (1-a-\lambda)(1-b-\lambda) - ab.$$

Setting  $det(P - λI) = 0$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $λ$ are the eigenvalues. For matrix $P$, we get:

$$ (1-a-\lambda)(1-b-\lambda) - ab = 0 $$

$$ \lambda^2 - (2-a-b)\lambda + 1 - a - b = 0 $$

$$ \lambda_{1,2} = \frac{(a+b-2) \pm \sqrt{(a+b-2)^2 - 4(1-a-b)}}{2} $$

By solving this, we can see that the Eigenvalues are $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = (1 - a - b,1)$

**Step 2: Find Eigenvectors**

If we know the Eigenvalues, the general procedure for finding out the Eigenvectors are given by:

$$(P - \lambda I)v = 0$$

- For $\lambda_1 = 1$, we get:

$$P - \lambda_1 I = \begin{bmatrix}
1-a-1 & a \\[5pt]
b & 1-b-1
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
-a & a \\[5pt]
b & -b
\end{bmatrix}.$$

To find $v = [v_{11}, v_{21}]^T$, we  solve:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-a & a \\[5pt]
b & -b
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
v_{11} \\[5pt]
v_{21}
\end{bmatrix} = 0.$$

$$-av_{11} + av_{21} = 0,$$
$$bv_{11} - bv_{21} = 0.$$

We see that:

$$v_{11} = v_{21}$$
$$v_1 = [1, 1]^T$$

- For $\lambda_1 = 1-a-b$, we get:

$$P - \lambda_2 I$$:

$$P - \lambda_2 I = \begin{bmatrix}
1-a-(1-a-b) & a \\[5pt]
b & 1-b-(1-a-b)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
b & a \\[5pt]
b & a
\end{bmatrix}.$$

To solve for the vector $v = [v_{12}, v_{22}]^T$ equal to zero, we need:

$$bv_{12} + av_{22} = 0,$$
$$bv_{12} + av_{22} = 0.$$

A  solution is when $v_{12} = a$ and $v_{22} = -b$. So, the eigenvector $v_2$ corresponding to $\lambda_2 = 1 - a - b$ is:

$$v_2 = [a, -b]^T$$

**Step 3: Diagonalization** Q is a matrix of Eigenvalues and D is a matrix of Eigenvectors

$$Q = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\[5pt]
1 & -b
\end{bmatrix},$$

$$D = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\[5pt]
0 & 1-a-b
\end{bmatrix}.$$

**Step 4: Calculate $P^n$:**

Using the formula (provided in the comments) $P^n = QD^nQ^{-1}$, we get:

$$Q = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\[5pt]
1 & -b
\end{bmatrix},$$

$$Q^{-1} = \frac{1}{\text{det}(Q)} \begin{bmatrix}
-b & -a \\[5pt]
-1 & 1
\end{bmatrix},$$

$$\text{det}(Q) = 1*(-b) - a*1 = -b - a$$

$$D^n = \begin{bmatrix}
1^n & 0 \\[5pt]
0 & (1-a-b)^n
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\[5pt]
0 & (1-a-b)^n
\end{bmatrix}.$$

**Step 5: Evaluate Limit**

$$P^n =  QD^nQ^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\[5pt]
1 & -b
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\[5pt]
0 & (1-a-b)^n
\end{bmatrix} \frac{1}{-a-b} \begin{bmatrix}
-b & -a \\[5pt]
-1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Prior to even taking the limit, we can see that the Q matrices will not be affected by the limit as they do not contain any $n$ terms.

Although not mentioned in the original question, the matrix $P$ is a transition matrix corresponding to a Discrete Time Markov Chain, thus $a$ and $b$ are both positive numbers between $0$ and $1$ (i.e. $a$ and $b$ are probabilities).

This means that $1 - (a-b)$ is also less than 1 but greater than 0. And we know for a fact that any number less than 1, when raised to the power of $n$, as $n$ approaches infinity, this number approaches 0.

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P^n = Q \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\[5pt]
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} Q^{-1}.$$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P^n = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\[5pt]
1 & -b
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\[5pt]
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \frac{1}{-a-b} \begin{bmatrix}
-b & -a \\[5pt]
-1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Doing some final re-arranging, we can see:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P^n = \frac{1}{a+b} \begin{bmatrix}
b & a \\[5pt]
b & a
\end{bmatrix},$$

Thus, the original claim has been proven! (woo hoo!)

- Note 1: For the above limit, I can clearly see that if I multiply this limit by some vector and then take the limit, it will have no impact on the limit. This indirectly shows the concept of the Limiting Distribution - regardless of your initial distribution, if the Limiting Distribution exists, then the Markov Chain will eventually reach this Limiting Distribution.
- Note 2: I just realized for the case where:

\begin{equation}
P = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\[5pt]
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

We can see that for large values of $n$, the $D$ matrix:

$$D^n = \begin{bmatrix}
1^n & 0 \\[5pt]
0 & (1-1-1)^n
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\[5pt]
0 & (-1)^n
\end{bmatrix}.$$

The $D$ matrix will always oscillate between negative and positive values and will not converge. This means that the limit for the $D$ matrix in this case does not exist. Thus, in general, no limiting distribution would exist.

Comment: There is no need to use eigenvalues to find $P^n$. This is a highschool level question. Write $P=I_2+Q$ and notice that the powers of $Q$ have the same form. Moreover, the entries are satisfying the following reccurence relation $a_{n+1}=-\frac{1}{a+b}a_n$, so they are easily found. Then use Newton binomial formula in order to get $P$.

Comment: I meant, to get $P^n$.